# How can I use wireless-info results to troubleshoot the problem with my wireless connection (20.04)

Tags: boot, wireless, 20.04

At the time of installing 20.04 from scratch (using a USB drive), all worked with some minor connection glitches... I continued to add additional software and in my mania (! ) inadvertently disabled my wifi connection. As I don't recall all the changes I had made, I'm hoping to track through the logs (where? Which one?) where the point of failure is.
My question is :
Where can I locate a step-by-step monitoring of the boot process?  I'm aware of a boot.log, but it's on my installer USB.

***** Update *****
Here is the result of wireless-info at Ubuntu Pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tj4yfWwh8r/

Comment: We can probably spot the issue from the results of the wireless info report. Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look.

Comment: The required driver for your device is built-in to recent Ubuntu versions. What is the response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rtl8723de`

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723be not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1009-gcp

Comment: But if I boot it up on a live USB system, it sets up the wifi just fine. Indeed, I have had few problems previously... Been using Ubuntu for 6 or 7 years.

Comment: Does the live USB include the 5.4.0-1009-gcp kernel version that I suspect you installed after installation? If you installed it manually, I wonder if you missed a step.

Comment: You have all the right assessment... When I put the USB drive in, I see a folder, "writable" on it... That folder has logs from previous installations.

Comment: Otherwise, I get an error : Unable to mount Ubuntu-MATE 20.04 LTS amd64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108200/discussion-between-chili555-and-thegeeko61).